# Add style when creating button with script Unity ui toolkit

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want to add a lot of buttons with a script. I want to style them, but I can't find a method to do so.

I want to do something like

```
            Button current = new Button();
            current.addStyle("button-style");
```

Is this possible?
UNITY UI **TOOLKIT**

When a button is clicked I run a function

```
public void displayChildrenIcons(GameObject parent, string type)
    {
 var root = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement;
        var displayArea = root.Q<VisualElement>("options");
        displayArea.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            Button current = new Button();
//How do I style this button before adding it?
            displayArea.Add(current);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the class [`IStyle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.IStyle.html). You can create one of these variables and change it so you can customimze style. Then assign it with `Button.style = IStle;`

```
public IStyle iStyle = new();

Button current = new();
curent.style = bStyle;
displayArea.Add(current);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see how this works. Ill add more code to the question above.

Comment: @LearningJava lol it was a lot simpler than I thought. (**Edited orginial answer**)